# Proving that $f$ and $g$ are identically $0$ on the entire domain

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

**Q:** Let $f$ and $g$ be two non-decreasing twice differentiable functions defined on an interval $(a,b)$ such that for each $x\in (a,b)$, $f''(x)=g(x)$ and $g''(x)=f(x)$. Suppose also that $f(x)g(x)$ is linear in $x$ on $(a,b)$. Show that we must have $f(x)=g(x)=0$ for all $x\in (a,b)$

**My solution:**

Since $f(x)g(x)$ is linear on $(a,b)$, we can write $f(x)g(x)=px+q~\forall~x\in (a,b)$ where $p,q$ are constants. Now, using chain rule twice, we have,

$$f''(x)g(x)+g''(x)f(x)+2f'(x)g'(x)=0~\forall~x\in (a,b)$$

Using $f''(x)=g(x)$ and $g''(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in (a,b)$, we can rewrite the above as,

$$(g(x))^2+(f(x))^2+2f'(x)g'(x)=0~\forall~x\in (a,b)\tag 1$$

Since square of a real number is always non-negative, we have $(g(x))^2,(f(x))^2\geq 0~\forall~x\in (a,b)$. Also, since $f,g$ are non-decreasing functions, we have $f'(x),g'(x)\geq 0~\forall~x\in (a,b)$ and hence $2f'(x)g'(x)\geq 0~\forall~x\in (a,b)$.

Since every term in the sum $(1)$ is non-negative and the sum equals $0$, the equality can hold iff every term of the sum is $0$.

Hence, we have $(f(x))^2=(g(x))^2=0~\forall~(a,b)$ which implies that $f(x)=g(x)=0~\forall~x\in (a,b)$

---

Is the above proof correct / rigorous enough?

Comment: Definitely looks good enough to me...

Comment: It looks good to me, too. However, there is a point not very clear to me. There is another definiton for _linear_ functions besides the one you used: $h$ is linear if $h(x+y)=h(x)+h(y)$ and $h(a y)=a h(y)$. Make sure (from the context where you took the question) which is the one you have to use.